# How to run a command in a Makefile if one file is newer than another?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to run some command (in the example below, `echo`) if one file ('glide.lock') is newer than a directory ('vendor').

On one operating system, this works:

```
deps:
    @test glide.lock -nt vendor; \
    RETVAL=$$?; \
    if [ $$RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then \
        echo dependencies out of date; \
    fi
```

But on another (Ubuntu), it doesn't. On both systems manually running `test glide.lock -nt vendor` and checking `$?` gives the correct answer.

How can I do this in the most compatible way possible?

Comment: Why not just `if test glide.lock -nt vendor; then echo ...; fi`?

Comment: That works on the machine that my version works on, but not on the one that it doesn't.

Comment: Do you want the makefile to do anything else with that file or that directory?

Comment: In addition to the echo, the real makefile creates or updates the contents of the directory. (The lock file is updated outside of the control of the Makefile.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but how about:

```
vendor: glide.lock
    echo dependencies out of date
```